# SQL Server adhoc query convert integer list to varchar

Tags: java, sql-server

I am using AdHoc query like this

```
SELECT MemberName 
FROM Member 
WHERE MemberNo IN (:memberNumberList)
```

However, MemberNo is varchar column and :memNumberList is list of nvarchar values. When I use single value, I convert integer variable to varchar like this.

```
SELECT MemberName
FROM Member
WHERE MemberNo = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), :memberNumber)
```

If I don't convert the variable, implicit conversion is happened. So I'd like to convert :memNumberList to varchar.

Is there any idea?

Here is JAVA code for it

MapSqlParameterSource param = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        param.addValue(“memberNumberList", memberNumberList);

```
    try {
        List<MemberInfo> list = jdbcTemplate.query(
                " SELECT MemberName " +
                        " FROM Member " +
                        " WHERE MemberNo IN (:memberNumberList) ",
                param, new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(MemberInfo.class));

        return list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(MemberInfo::getMemberNumber, Function.identity()));
    } catch (DataAccessException e) {
        throw new MemberException(“There is an issue to search member (+" + e.getMessage() + ")", e);
    }
```